# "x.Groups = list" works but "x.Groups.Add(listItem)" throws Null Reference Exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have a class, called `Permissions`, it has a few subclasses (and some properties), `Group` and `Group.Permission`.

Now, I ***CAN*** do the following

```
Permissions u = new Permissions();
u.userId = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
List<int> groups = getGroupsForUserId(u.userId.ToString());

List<Permissions.Group> groupItems = new List<Permissions.Group>();

foreach (int g in groups)
{
    Permissions.Group groupItem = new Permissions.Group();
    groupItem.group_id = g;
    groupItem.Records = getRecordsForGroupId(g);
    groupItem.Permissions = getPermissionsForGroupId(g);

    groupItems.Add(groupItem);
}
u.Groups = groupItems;
```

However, I ***CAN'T*** do this:

```
Permissions u = new Permissions();
u.userId = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
List<int> groups = getGroupsForUserId(u.userId.ToString());

foreach (int g in groups)
{
    Permissions.Group groupItem = new Permissions.Group();
    groupItem.group_id = g;
    groupItem.Records = getRecordsForGroupId(g);
    groupItem.Permissions = getPermissionsForGroupId(g);

    u.Groups.Add(groupItem);
}
```

My question, ***why?***

I created a new `Permissions.Group` object, added the values and then added it to the `u` object's list of `Groups`. To my mind that should work, however I assume I've not wired something up in my class? My class just is a list of properties `property_name { get; set; }` so isn't anything exotic really.

Trying the latter, I get a `NullReferenceException` on the line `u.Groups.Add(groupItem);`

Comment: Show us the `Permissions` class.

Comment: Well, which expression (to the *left* of a `.`) **is** null? It's the same story every time... too localized. (Also, there is nothing inherently "OOP" in this question.)

Comment: @pst : I think you meant to the left ^^

Comment: @jrummell has answered my question. @pst - apologies for not being OOP enough, whilst it's just basic classes and such like to you I'm still learning - the Permissions.Group is a `List<Groups>` and so the .Add is a method of the fact it's a `List` AFAIK. I could see that `u` was initiated / instantizied, however couldn't work out why `Groups` wasn't available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to initialize `Permissions.Groups` in your `Permissions` constructor:

```
public class Permissions
{
    public Permissions()
    {
         Groups = new List<Group>();
    }

    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Bang on the money! Thank you, I'll mark as answered when I'm allowed.

Comment: Just want to add, I've been pouring over a ton of tutorials and I can't find any mention of this snippet, so thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, my money is on the fact that you aren't initializing the Groups collection in Permissions object.  So, in essence, you are attempting to add a group item to a null Groups collection.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't instantiated `User.Groups` yet, it still is null. Either in the constructor of `User` or after instantiating `User` you have to also instantiate the `Groups` property/field.

```
public class Permissions
{
    public List<Premissions.Group> Groups { get; set; }
    ...
    public Permissions()
    {
        Groups = new List<Permissions.Group>();
    }
}
```

OR

```
Permissions user = new Permissions();
user.Groups = new List<Permissions.Group>();
```

OR

```
public class Permissions
{
    private List<Permissions.Group> _groups = new List<Permissions.Group>();
    public List<Permissions.Group> Groups { get { return _groups; } set { _groups = value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize Groups in the Permissions constructor.

Alternatively, If you do not want to modify the constructor, you can use [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Example:

Change
    Permissions u = new Permissions();

to

```
Permissions u = new Permissions(){Groups = new List<Permissions.Group>()};
```

In the object initializer, Groups is initialized to an empty List.